# subversion permissions on files in .svn

Tags: svn, unix, permissions, umask

I am setting up a shared working copy for web development.  Most of the users are not unix/command line capable so they are connecting to the working copy on the webserver via Samba and using TortoiseSVN.  I have set up default umask on bash and samba to give read/write access to user and group.  I've made all the users default group "webteam" which they all belong to.  This means any file they create is writable by them and other member of the team.

We are using svn version 1.6 (as it is the default on RHEL).  The umask and group ownership stuff works fine, but when I run the checkout:

```
# svn co svn://scythia/www .
```

If I then go into a directory with some files, first I check the permissions of the .svn dir:

```
drwxrwxr-x   6 geofa webteam 4096 Jul  3 09:28 .svn
```

That is what I want.  The same goes for all the sub directories.  But the files get the wrong permissions:

```
[geofa@scythia dac_property]$ ll .svn
total 20
-r--r--r-- 1 geofa webteam  838 Jul  3 09:28 entries
drwxrwxr-x 2 geofa webteam 4096 Jul  3 09:28 prop-base
drwxrwxr-x 2 geofa webteam 4096 Jul  3 09:28 props
drwxrwxr-x 2 geofa webteam 4096 Jul  3 09:28 text-base
drwxrwxr-x 5 geofa webteam 4096 Jul  3 09:28 tmp
```

All the files get the same read only settings:

```
[geofa@scythia .svn]$ ll prop-base/
total 16
-r--r--r-- 1 geofa webteam 30 Jul  3 09:28 dac_property.info.svn-base
-r--r--r-- 1 geofa webteam 30 Jul  3 09:28 dac_property.module.svn-base
-r--r--r-- 1 geofa webteam 30 Jul  3 09:28 dac_property.pages.inc.svn-base
-r--r--r-- 1 geofa webteam 30 Jul  3 09:28 dac_property_results.pages.inc.svn-base
```

These permissions mean that it works fine for me (geofa), but all the other users get permission denied.  Is there a umask setting for SVN somewhere?

Comment: Be wary of this setup (shared checkouts over network).  If anyone touches the checkout with a newer version of the svn client (like TortoiseSVN), the .svn stuff may be 'upgraded' and force all other users to upgrade before they can access the working copy again.

Comment: We have about 5 users, and we set up subversion on all the machines, so we ensure that everyone is on the same version.  The problem is the having multiple working copies just isn't in the cards.

Comment: Multiple users sharing a working copy is an anti-pattern in Subversion. Aside from the permissions problems, you're going to end up with users stepping all over each other and you've lost all accountability - it's trivial for a user to commit another user's changes. Fix this problem by not creating it in the first place.

Comment: That's not really the question I asked, I'm asking about permission behavior of SVN.  There is plenty of commentary on the web about shared working copies so I'm not the only one doing it.